# Who knocks at the door? Who does knock at the door?

Tags: questions

> 1. Who knocks at the door?
> 2. Who does knock at the door?

Hello, teachers. I am confused here. Usually, first sentence is acceptable. 
But I did not read about the second sentence. 
Is it correct? Is it an emphatic sentence of present indefinite tense?

Comment: This question was [cross-posted on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62498/who-knocks-at-the-door-who-does-knock-at-the-door). I'm not sure what policy is.

Comment: Duplicate. See http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62446/use-does-in-front-of-another-verb-in-a-question/62505#62505

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been posted on ELL.SE, which it is better suited for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ordinary sentences we distinguish questions from statements by flipping the subject and the auxiliary verb (Subj/Aux inversion), and if there is no auxiliary in the statement form, we bring in do to serve the auxiliary function (Do support):

Jace knocks at the door  →Q: Does Jace knock at the door?
But when you ask a question using a wh- word (including how), the wh- word is what tells your hearer that this is a question; there is no need for Subj/Aux inversion, and therefore no need for Do support either:

Who knocks at the door?

Comment: Can you please tell me which sentence is correct? Can't this sentence be right? Who does knock at the door?

Comment: Who does knock at the door? Is it not an emphatic sentence of present simple tense?